# How to count child XElements in where clause

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

```
<Automobiles>
  <Cars>
    <YearofMfr></YearofMfr>
    <Mileage></Mileage>
    <MeterReading></MeterReading>
    <Color></Color>
    <Condition></Condition>
  </Cars>
  <Cars>
    <YearofMfr></YearofMfr>
    <Color></Color>
    <Condition></Condition>
  </Cars>
</Automobiles>
```

How can I get an element which has all the child elements. To explain in detail. I have above xml. From this I want to retrieve single node which has all the child nodes. If you see in the second  node some information is missing. I tried doing this.

```
var nodes = from nodeElements in doc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault().Elements()
                 where doc.Descendants().Count()==5
                select nodeElements;
```

I need a single  node as output which has 5 child elements.

```
<Cars>     
<YearofMfr></YearofMfr>     
<Mileage></Mileage>     
<MeterReading></MeterReading>     
<Color></Color>     
<Condition></Condition>   
</Cars>
```

Comment: It's rather difficult to understand what do you want. Could you add some xml and describe output you need?

Comment: Prefer `doc.Root` instead of `doc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: This query is solved. But still rephrased my question for guys who have similar issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you select your count from nodeElements.Descendants instead:

```
var nodes = (from nodeElements in doc.Root.Elements()
            where nodeElements.Descendants().Count()==5
            select nodeElements).FirstOrDefault();
```

Updated to reflect the comment below and the comment to your original question.

Comment: Thanks a ton for responding super fast. Daniel's response worked. StackOverFlow Rocks!!!

Comment: If I use XDocument as the source object(i.e. doc) the above example is working fine. But its returning null if I use XElement. Sorry for troubling you again...

Comment: I have added a question regarding "finding duplicate xelements" here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076772/find-duplicate-xelements. @daniel-hilgarth Please helpout.

Comment: I guess there is a difference between querying XDocument & XElement.When I used XDocument as source the below query worked.
var nodes = (from nodeElements in doc.Root.Elements()             where nodeElements.Descendants().Count()==5 select nodeElements).FirstOrDefault(); 
When I changed the source to XElement. I had to change to
IEnumerable<XElement> nodes = (from nodeElements in payLoad.DescendantsAndSelf().Elements()
where nodeElements.Descendants().Count() == 5
select nodeElements);
Main difference here abv 2 queries is doc.Root.Elements() and payLoad.DescendantsAndSelf().Elements().