# Find duplicate xelements

Tags: xml, linq, group-by, duplicates, distinct

I have the below XML

```
<Automobiles>
  <Cars>
    <YearofMfr>2010</YearofMfr>
    <Mileage>12</Mileage>
    <MeterReading>1500</MeterReading>
    <Color>Red</Color>
    <Condition>Excellent</Condition>
  </Cars>
  <Cars>
    <YearofMfr>2010</YearofMfr>
    <Mileage>12</Mileage>
    <MeterReading>1500</MeterReading>
    <Color>Red</Color>
    <Condition>Excellent</Condition>
  </Cars>
  <Cars>
    <YearofMfr>2008</YearofMfr>
    <Mileage>11</Mileage>
    <MeterReading>20000</MeterReading>
    <Color>Pearl White</Color>
    <Condition>Good</Condition>
  </Cars>
</Automobiles>
```

I was looking for a LINQ Query which would return duplicate  nodes. In the above XML there are two  nodes which are similar. The result should include both the duplicate nodes.

I also need a query which would return all the nodes which are not duplicate. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest, you create a `Car` class and create a list of `Car` instances from the XML and do your analysis on that list.
It would simplify things, because you could overwrite the `Equals` method of the `Car` class to only return true, if all properties are the same.

Answer (score 5):

This query would result in the list of duplicate `Cars` entries in your XML, you could take it from there:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");
var duplicates = doc.Descendants("Cars")
                    .GroupBy(c => c.ToString())
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(g => g.First())
                    .ToList();
```

There's no point in including more than one node for each duplicate in the list because..well they're duplicates. Similarly you can filter out the nodes that are **not** duplicates with any other Cars node, just change the where condition:

```
var uniqueCars = doc.Descendants("Cars")
                    .GroupBy(c => c.ToString())
                    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                    .Select(g => g.First())
                    .ToList();
```