# Search for double values in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a short question to work in C# with an XML file

I would like to search double entries where the code is more then one time in the XML File.
I have tried it with an XMLReader but I don't know how I can write the double product entries in a new XML File.
The problem is that I would like to write the complete "product" in a new list when the "code" is more then one time in a XML File.

I have following XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rescue>
<product>
 <key>0E25</key>
 <name>Hi World</name>
 <code>35646546546</code>
</product>

<product>
 <key>01EBC</key>
 <name>World</name>
 <code>123456789</code>
</product>

<product>
 <key>OC5999</key>
 <name>Double</name>
 <code>35646546546</code>
</product>
</rescue>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the complete product"? There will naturally be multiple entries for that product - do you want to write them all out? What have you tried so far? I'd recommend using LINQ to XML. A simple query should be able to build you a `Lookup<string, XElement>` - a dictionary from each code to the product elements for that code. You can then do whatever you like with the entries that have more than one value.

Comment: I would like to write the product (from <product> over <key>,<name>,<code> to </product> in a new XML file. In the example the third product (<product>
 <key>OC5999</key>
 <name>Double</name>
 <code>35646546546</code>
</product>
) must be cut of an write to a new list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible option is to create a class `Product` which holds the values for each product. You could then use the `XmlReader` to read the products, use LINQ to sort out the duplicates and finally use `XmlWriter` to write the duplicates to a seperate file. A fast implementation would be;

```
public class Product
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class ReadAndWrite
{
    var productList = new List<Product>();

    using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("path/to/file.xml"))
    {
        Product p;
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            if(reader.IsStartElement())
            {
                switch(reader.Name)
                {
                    case "product": 
                        p = new Product(); 
                        break;

                    case "code" :
                        reader.Read(); //Point it one step forward to read the value
                        p.Code = reader.Value;
                        break;

                    //Etc...                           
                }
            }

            if(reader.Name == "product" && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                productList.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }

    var duplicates = productList.GroupBy(p => p.Code).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).SelectMany(v => v).ToList();

    using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("path/to/duplicates.xml"))
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Duplicates");

        foreach(var duplicate in duplicates)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Product");

            writer.WriteElementString("Name", duplicate.Name);
            //Etc...

            writer.WriteEndElement()
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That's help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `XElement`.

```
XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);  // xml-string, alternativeley, use XElement.Load("path/to/file.xml")
            var doc = XElement.Parse(xml);

IEnumerable<XElement> products;
products = doc.Descendants("product")
    .Where(e =>
        {
            var xElement = e.Element("name");
            return xElement != null && xElement.Value == "Double";
        })
    .GroupBy(e => e.ToString())
    .Where(e => e.Count() > 1)
    .Select(p => p.First());
```

Also, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076772/find-duplicate-xelements).